# Perspective not working when transformation applied to img in firefox or ie10?

Tags: html, css

When I apply transform to image, it transforms but in 2d way. perspective doesn't seems to work. However its perfect in opera/chrome.
When I apply to div of image, perspective works perfectly.
Here's my code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing Scripts</title>
        <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="script/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="slider">
       <div class="sliced"><img src="images/1.jpg"></div>
    </div>
    </body> 
 </html>
```

style.css

```
body {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 100px auto;
 }
.slider {
    -webkit-perspective : 600px;
    -moz-perspective : 600px;
    position: relative;

 }
 .sliced {
    position: absolute;


 }
.sliced img{
    -webkit-transform : rotateX(80deg);
    -moz-transform : rotateX(80deg);
}
```

If I change it to

```
.sliced{
    -webkit-transform : rotateX(80deg);
    -moz-transform : rotateX(80deg);
    }
```

It works prefectly.
Any reasons or i am missing something?
[Here is my code pen](http://codepen.io/gautam/pen/pisDH)

Comment: [Here](http://codepen.io/gautam/pen/pisDH)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Firefox, perspective has to be applied in the parent where you apply the transform. (i don't know exactly why).

So, with an HTML where the relationship is slider > sliced > img your CSS doesn't work (slider is not the parent of the img). It will work if you rotate the sliced, as you say.

Another posibility to make it work is to set

```
.slider {
    -webkit-perspective : 600px;
    position: relative;

 }
 .sliced {
    -moz-perspective : 600px;
}
```

This way, perspective is in the parent of the image (for firefox) and it will work.

Comment: It has been raised as bug in Firefox but it's really a difference in implementation of the standard - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23082686/637889

Answer (score 0):

You have added transformation for webkit and mozilla and havent declared anything for others. Try this one and it works fine:

```
    .sliced img{
        -webkit-transform : rotateX(80deg);
        -moz-transform : rotateX(80deg);
         transform: rotate(80deg);
    }
```

Comment: It is better to declare non-prefixed property the last, so it will be preferred if browser supports it.

Comment: thanks for reply. But doesn't works [Take a look] (http://img109.imageshack.us/img109/1364/8i6q.jpg)

Comment: I checked on IE 10 and it works. Which browser did you check?

Comment: FireFox, take a look at my screenshot given above.