# CSS perspective not working in Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, css-transforms

This is probably the simplest question anyone has ever asked on SO but my mind is drawing a blank this morning. Maybe I need more coffee.

Basically I'm trying to add some CSS3 transform effects to an element and for whatever reason Firefox isn't playing ball.

If you take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d74vr/) in Chrome you'll see what I want, then if you look at it in Firefox you'll see that it's not the same...

This is the CSS for that particular element;

```
-webkit-transform: rotateY(60deg) scale(0.9);
-ms-transform: rotateY(60deg) scale(0.9);
transform: rotateY(60deg) scale(0.9);
```

Am I just missing a property or something?

Comment: You need to add `-moz` prefix for firefox.

Comment: @Vucko I had a `-moz` prefix originally but it made no difference so I removed it. I've just tried it in my fiddle too and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are seeing [Bug 716524 - 'perspective' only affects child nodes, not further descendants](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=716524). The defect describes that there is a difference between Chrome and Firefox in their interpretation of what *inherited* means. It looks like it should not be inherited, according to [`perspective`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) MDN documentation but I sort of agree with Chrome as it feels intuitive to propagate it to descendants.

I tried the workaround from [3D transformations with Firefox 10+](http://blog.joelambert.co.uk/2012/02/13/3d-transformations-with-firefox-10/) which recommends reapplying `transform-style: preserve-3d` (with or without the `-moz-` depending on which versions of Firefox you care about supporting) at each depth but that still wasn't working for me.

Moving `perspective` and `perspective-origin` to the `<ul>` fixes the problem in Firefox.

Answer (score 8):

**POSSIBLE WORKAROUND:** In case this helps anyone... I just found that in Firefox you can add `transform-style: inherit;` to all elements between the element with `perspective` set and the element being transformed and you should see your transform.

**NOTE:** You must set `transform-style: preserve-3d;` on the element with `perspective` set for this to work.

This is a bit hacky but until they change the implementation this seems to be the only way I could find to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In mozilla firbox perspective property may still not work.
So you can add this command:
-moz-perspective: (write your value with measuring units like 10rem etc)
perspective property work for all others browsers so only for firbox obove comand is used.
Thanks