# Perspective CSS3 Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

I am trying to develop a card flip animation in X axis direction. As of now, `div` now simply rotates using rotateX() method. I have tried using perspective property to the upper div, instead of working it distorts my div structure. Since, it is just a working stage, I am only targeting google chrome.
Please see it on [codepen](http://codepen.io/grvtiwari/pen/NPbjOO).

Here is my HTML code.

```
<div class="wrapper">
                <div class="upper">
                    <div class="upper-current">
                        <div class="content">
                            1
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="upper-next">
                        <div class="content">
                            2
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="lower">
                    <div class="lower-current">
                        <div class="content">
                            1
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="lower-next">
                        <div class="content">
                            2
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

And my CSS,
div.row{
                width: 150px;
                height: 200px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }

```
        div.wrapper{
            background-color: #444;
            width: 150px;
            height: 200px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            position:relative;

        }

        div.wrapper div.upper, div.wrapper div.lower{
            height: 100px;
            width:100%;

        }

        div.upper-current{
            transition :all 1s;
            transform-origin: 50% 100%;
        }

        div.wrapper > div.upper > div, div.wrapper > div.lower > div{
            height: 100px;
            width:100%;
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            overflow:hidden;
            text-align:center;
            background-color:#444;
        }

        div.wrapper > div.upper > div{
            border-bottom: 3px solid #333;
        }

        div.wrapper > div.lower > div{
            height: 200px;
        }

        div.upper-current{
            z-index: 4;
        }

        div.upper-next{
            z-index: 3;
        }

        div.lower-current{
            z-index: 2;
        }

        div.lower-next{
            z-index: 1;
        }

        div.content{
            position: relative;
            top: -24px;
        }
```

I am trying to achieve this effect. 
[image: Top edge is larger, it looks like coming out.]

But with my code, I am simply gettting.
[image: Plain rotate effect.]

Comment: what is problem you face

Comment: After using perspective, the top edge should appear closer or in simple words, consider door open effect. to a user.

I am using perspective, even then I am receiving a simple plain rotateX effect

Comment: Probably, I am not clear enough.

RotateX effect is working completly.

however, perspective is not. 

Top.edge of rotating div should enlarge or should appear larger than the lower edge as it happens on horizontal card.flip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
This [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEqMNM) should work on firefox, too.  Because of the stacking context problem, I just made `.upper` `relative` and gave it a z-index so it would be above `.lower`.

If you put the `perspective` CSS property on  `.wrapper` it should work: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNBLdo)

[Perspective](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) creates a new stacking context so if you put it on `.upper`, all of your upper `<div>` `z-index`'s are no longer in the same context as the lower ones and the lower ones are on top because of the natural HTML stacking.

Comment: I think I understood. Does the codepen in my answer not do the perspective for you? Its working on chrome for me.

Comment: I don't understand. It is now showing the perspective now. At least 12 hours ago, I tried the same with latest version of firefox, but it was not working. On the other hand, same was working with the other js.

Comment: Hmmm i just checked this out and it looks like Firefox and WebKit disagree on how perspective works. See this stack overflow q:[css perspective not working in firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080112/css-perspective-not-working-in-firefox).