# Perspective property in Firefox causes transform to behave different than chrome and not as desired

Tags: html, css, firefox, 3d, perspective

There is a very similar [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23080112/css-perspective-not-working-in-firefox), but it is quite old and the solutions do not work for me.

I have a turning page effect which uses the `transform-style:preserve-3d` and `perspective`, to create a 3D page then the turning page effect is animated with keyframes, using buttons to apply and remove a style with each keyframe.

The problem is with the perspective property, if this is removed, I lose the 3D effect but it works ok in both firefox and chrome.  With the perspective set, the page turning effect appears incorrect in **firefox only**, it appears as though the page is pulled downward as it turns.  In chrome, it works fine and the page turning effect appears as you would expect a page in a book to look like as it turns (as though the page goes up as it turns). The front of the page is red and the back is green.

I would like to retain the 3d effect with perspective set to 1000px and for the page to turn in firefox like it does in chrome.

I would appreciate if anyone has a a solution or workaround.

```js
function turnLeft() {
  page = document.getElementById('page');
  page.classList.remove('turnRight')
  page.classList.add('turnLeft')
}

function turnRight() {
  page = document.getElementById('page');
  page.classList.remove('turnLeft')
  page.classList.add('turnRight')
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.page {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 25%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotateX(25deg);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) rotateX(25deg);
  border: solid 1px black;
  transform-origin: 0% 45%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-color: red;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.back {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: solid 2px #000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
  background-color: green;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.turnLeft {
  -moz-animation: turnPageToLeft 0.4s ease-in 0s 1 normal forwards;
  animation: turnPageToLeft 0.4s ease-in 0s 1 normal forwards;
}

.turnRight {
  -moz-animation: turnPageToRight 0.4s ease-in 0s 1 normal forwards;
  animation: turnPageToRight 0.4s ease-in 0s 1 normal forwards;
}

@keyframes turnPageToLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotateX(25deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -180deg) translateY(-51%) rotateX(-25deg) scale(1, 0.99);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes turnPageToLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotateX(25deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -180deg) translateY(-51%) rotateX(-25deg) scale(1, 0.99);
  }
}

@keyframes turnPageToRight {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -180deg) translateY(-51%) rotateX(-25deg)scale(1, 0.99);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotateX(25deg);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes turnPageToRight {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -180deg) translateY(-51%) rotateX(-25deg)scale(1, 0.99);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotateX(25deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="page" class="page">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="turnLeft()">Turn Left</button>
  <button onclick="turnRight()">Turn Right</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this bit from:

```
transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -180deg)
```

to:

```
transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -179deg)
```

Technically there are two correct ways to animate from 180 to -180; Firefox just happens to pick the "downward and away" path that looks wrong for this particular effect. By tweaking the animation from 180 to -179, it ensures the "up and over" path is the shorter one, thus always picked by both browsers.

```js
function turnLeft() {
  page = document.getElementById('page');
  page.classList.remove('turnRight')
  page.classList.add('turnLeft')
}

function turnRight() {
  page = document.getElementById('page');
  page.classList.remove('turnLeft')
  page.classList.add('turnRight')
}
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.page {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 25%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotateX(25deg);
  border: solid 1px black;
  transform-origin: 0% 45%;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.front {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background-color: red;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.back {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: solid 2px #000;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, 180deg);
  background-color: green;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.turnLeft {
  animation: turnPageToLeft 0.4s ease-in 0s 1 normal forwards;
}

.turnRight {
  animation: turnPageToRight 0.4s ease-in 0s 1 normal forwards;
}

@keyframes turnPageToLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotateX(25deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -179deg) translateY(-51%) rotateX(-25deg);
  }
}


@keyframes turnPageToRight {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(0, 1, 0, -179deg) translateY(-51%) rotateX(-25deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-50%) rotateX(25deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="page" class="page">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="turnLeft()">Turn Left</button>
  <button onclick="turnRight()">Turn Right</button>
</body>
```